# How do we know that $F[\alpha]$ is a ring?

Tags: field-theory

Note that this question is *not* about the proposition $\alpha$ is algebraic over $F \iff F[\alpha] = F(\alpha)$

I've got the following note in my textbook (given without proof, suggesting the statement is rather trivial), but I've been having some difficulty with it:

Given field $F$, extension field $L/F$ and $\alpha\in L$ then $F[\alpha] = \{a_0 + \alpha a_1 + \cdots + \alpha^m a_m:a_1,\ldots,a_m \in F\}$ is the smallest subring of $L$ containing $\alpha$.

If this is indeed a ring, I agree that it is the smallest, but how do we know that this is indeed a ring? If we have some finite ring $R$ with $m$ elements, then $\alpha^{m+1} \not \in F[\alpha]$ (or so it seems to me), and thus $F[\alpha]$ isn't closed.

Thanks

Comment: If any ring is finite, then the powers of a fixed element cannot all be distinct. So it must be that $\alpha^j=\alpha^k$ for some positive integers $j<k.$

Comment: I see what you're saying but what I'm having difficulty with is the fact that $\alpha$ comes from $L$, not $F$, and I don't see why we couldn't "unlock" elements of higher order than $\#F$

Comment: Just above your definition of $F(\alpha)$ you have written $\alpha \in F.$ I think you ment $\alpha \in L.$ since $L$ is an extension field of $F$ it is in particular a field. From your description one can choose the coefficients $a_i$ appropriately to show that both $\alpha$ and $\alpha^m$ are members of $L.$ Therefore their product $\alpha^{n+1}$ is in $L,$ since $L$ is a field.

Comment: $m$ is never defined. Is it supposed to be a specific number, fixed throughout, or an arbitrary nonnegative integer that can vary depending on the element?

Comment: When you say "Given field $F$, extension field $L/F$ and $\alpha\in F$", do you mean $\alpha\in L$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an implicit quantification over $m$ here; it might be clearer to write $$F[\alpha]=\{a_0+\alpha a_1+\alpha^2a_2+...+\alpha^ma_m: \color{red}{m\in\mathbb{N}}, a_1,...,a_m\in F\}.$$ There are three key points here:

- $m$ is **not fixed**, and elements of $F[\alpha]$ are allowed to be "arbitrarily (finitely) long."
- There is no requirement that the $a_i$s be **distinct**.
- Different sequences **may** name the same element of $L$ (and so of $F[\alpha]$); more abstractly, the obvious homomorphism $F[X]\rightarrow F[\alpha]$ need not be injective.

This should eliminate your concerns about running out of elements if $F$ (or even $L$) is finite. For example, if $F=\mathbb{F}_2$, $L=\mathbb{F}_4$ *(where for prime $p$ $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ is the unique-up-to-isomorphism finite field of cardinality $p^n$ - note that $\mathbb{F}_2$ sits inside $\mathbb{F}_4$ in a unique way)*, and $\alpha\in L\setminus F$, one of the elements of $F[\alpha]$ is the sum $$\gamma:=1+\alpha+\alpha^2+\alpha^3+\alpha^4+\alpha^5+\alpha^6+\alpha^7.$$ This element $\gamma$ is defined by a sequence of length longer than even the size of $L$, but that's not a problem; it still is an element of $F[\alpha]$.